# How to make Symfony passwordless authentication (OTP via SMS)?

Tags: symfony

Does anyone knows if there are any Symfony bundles for a passwordless login (via SMS code)? Thats a quite common feature nowadays and I was quite surprised Symfony does not provide it from core and neither I found any 3rd party bundles

I know there is 2fa bundle by it sends code *after* login. I just need a login by sms code.

Did not found any symfony bundles for OTP login via sms code

Answer (score 0):

[Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#login-programmatically)

As example

- you can create entity OptLogin (user_id, code)
- find user via OptLogin when user provide code
- log in a user programmatically using the login() method of the Security helper